# Java Shift Operator and auto promotion

Tags: java, bit-shift

I'm a newbie Java programmer, who is reading [Thinking In Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131872486) by Bruce Eckel.

In the 5th chapter, operators have been discussed. Where it is talking about shift operators (<<, >>, >>>) he says:

> If you shift a char, byte, or short, it will be promoted to int before
>   the shift takes place, and the result will be an int. **Only the five
>   low-order bits of the right-hand side will be used**. This prevents
>   you from shifting more than the number of bits in an int. If you’re
>   operating on a long, you’ll get a long result. **Only the six
>   low-order bits of the right-hand side will be used**, so you can’t
>   shift more than the number of bits in a long.

Which I can't understand the meaning. Specially the bold sentences. Could you clarify it a bit?

Comment: @Pawan normally high/low order refers to the location of the bits, not their value

Comment: @Pawan: why 5 low-order or 6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel that the other answers are a bit incomplete.

It's true that an `int` is 32 bits, and the language doesn't let you shift more than 32 bits.  What's gotten left out is that if you tell it to shift more than 32 bits, the shift amount will be taken modulo 32.  That is, if `x` is an `int`, `x >> 32` is the same as `x >> 0` (i.e. just `x`), `x >> 33` is the same as `x >> 1`, `x >> 66` is the same as `x >> 2`, etc.  Using only the low-order 5 bits of the right argument is the same as taking the argument modulo 32 (using the mathematical definition, so that -1 mod 32 == 31, -2 mod 32 == 30, etc.).

Similarly, `long` is 64 bits, which means that the right argument is computed modulo 64, which is the same as using only the low-order 6 bits of the right argument.

Why Java did it this way, I don't know.  In my opinion, it would be more consistent if it simply let you shift by a large amount, shifting all the bits out of the integer and resulting in 0 (except that `>>` sign-extends, so the result would be 0 or -1).  It would be consistent mathematically, because for positive `x` and `y`, `x >> y` would always be equal to `x / (2^y)` truncated down to an integer, even if `y` >= 32.  Java's way of handling shift amounts that are >= 32 or >= 64 isn't useful in any way I can see.

Comment: The modulus matches some architectures' shift instructions, which is probably why they defined it that way.

Comment: Right, I thought of that, but at first it didn't seem to make sense to define the JVM architecture to do the same thing--it's a virtual machine, after all.  But if JVM code does get translated to native code (I'm really not sure how that all works), then perhaps it does make sense that it would be more efficient, on some processors, if the shift were in a tight loop.  Of course it wouldn't help with processors that don't work that way.

Answer (score 3):

The result of a shift operation is interpreted as either `int` or `long` depending on the **left side**.

`int` (32 bits) when the left side is `int` or lower (8 bit `byte`, 16 bit `char`, 16 bit `short`)

`long` (64 bits) when the left side is `long`

In order to limit the result to these bounds, the **right side** must be limited in the following way:

> Only the five low-order bits of the right-hand side will be used.

Won't allow shifts over 31  (%0001 1111)

> Only the six low-order bits of the right-hand side will be used.

Won't allow shifts over 63  (%0011 1111)

If you use a larger number than accepted, the result will only use the lower bits (more to the right) effectively performing a modulo operation by 32 or 64.

Comment: I didn't refer to the Oracle documentation, just going by what @kikio mentioned in the post

Answer (score 1):

He's referring the the number of bits used from the number you're shifting by, so for an int the "five low-order bits of the right-hand side" gives you 5 bits = 2 ^ 5 = 32 bits that you can shift ints by.  Similarly, six bits = 2 ^ 6 = 64, so you can only shift longs by 64 bits.  Note that those numbers correspond to the size of int and long respectively.